# How can I add all the values in the string list to a single string?

Tags: java

`restApplication.getPurposeOfTheLoans ()` is a list of string type. `limit.getPurpose ()` is a single string value. I want to add all string statements in this list end to end and set them to the `limit.setPurpose()` statement. How can I do that? I shared my sample code below.

**Java sample**

```
String pOfLoan = "";
for (int i = 0; i < restApplication.getPurposeOfTheLoans().size(); i++) {
    pOfLoan.concat(restApplication.getPurposeOfTheLoans().get(i) + " ");
    limit.setPurpose(pOfLoan);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stream api `collect`:

```
pOfLoan = restApplication.getPurposeOfTheLoans().stream() // stream
              .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")); // join
```

Better alternative:

```
pOfLoan = String.join(" ", restApplication.getPurposeOfLoans());
```

Comment: Does it leave a gap when I use stream api and join?

Comment: @okoreni Yes. See `joining(" ")`. Anything you add as param will be used for joining. If you don't want anything, don't specify anything.

Comment: @okoreni https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: `String.join(" ", restApplication.getPurposeOfLoans())` is neater.

Answer (score 0):

```
String pOfLoan = ""; 
for(int i=0;i<restApplication.getPurposeOfTheLoans().size();i++){ 
pOfLoan = pOfLoan.concat(restApplication.getPurposeOfTheLoans().get(i)+" "); 
}
limit.setPurpose(pOfLoan);
```

you forgot to assign return value of concat

Comment: Bad idea, better use string builder if you are doing this in a `for` loop.